# Consume WCF Service in Windows Phone application: methods return void

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

I have WCF service

When I "Add Service Reference" in my windows phone application everything looks good but methods return void. I tested this server for example in WPF app and it works and returns what I need but in wp 7/8 app not. Ofcourse the basic functionality of this WCF is to return data so void methods are totally useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use service `Async` and `Completed` events.Service will return data in `completed` event like

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client clientForTesting = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            clientForTesting.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(TestCallback);
            clientForTesting.GetDataAsync(testValue);
```

Comment: I've already done that thanks, but could anyone tell me why in WPF application Async methods return values but in windows phone app (7 or 8) add service reference generates void methods :( ?